# How to create and use an Array?

Tags: workflow, youtrack

I can't figure out how to declare a simple array in YouTrack's workflow editor.  Can anyone help?

I've tried

```
var userList = [];
var userList[];
var userList();
```

Nothing works.

[Here is the sum of their "documentation" on variables...](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/YTD5/Variables)

Comment: What language is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workflow language supports only the following predefined collections: *issues*, *comments*, *tags*, *users*, *issue links*, *enum elements*, *versions*, *builds*, *ownedFields*, *groups*, *states*, *bundle static elements*, *strings*.

As far as I know custom user-defined collections/arrays are not supported at all.

Source: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/YTD5/Workflow+Language+Quick+Reference#WorkflowLanguageQuickReference-Iteratorsandcollections

Answer (score 1):

The only workaround is use string arrays.

```
var array = "1,2,3".split(",", opts);
```

after that you can use array.contains or for each. If you need to dinamicaly create array then you can add values after that resplit and reassign.

```
var values = "1,2,3";
var array = values.split(",", opts); 
var appendval = "4"; 
if (!array.contains(appendval)) { 
  values = values + "," + appendval; 
  array = values.split(",", opts); 
}
```

Comment: I tried this on YouTrack 2019.3, but it didn't work. Btw, what does `opts` mean?